# Registering serializers in Storm config

Tags: scala, apache-storm

I want to register serializers for Scala collections in my storm topology. I am using twitter chill KryoSerializer for this purpose.

What i am doing is 
1. Created a decorator which implements IKryoDecorator. In the decorate method i call KryoSerializer.registerAll(k) where k is a Kyro instance 
2. In the topology  config object I call registerDecorator method.

```
import com.twitter.chill.KryoSerializer
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.Kryo
import backtype.storm.serialization.IKryoDecorator

class KryoDecorator extends IKryoDecorator {
  def decorate(k: Kryo) {
    KryoSerializer.registerAll(k)
  }
}
```

and then

```
stormConfig.registerDecorator(classOf[ReflexKryoDecorator])
```

Still when i run the topology i get exception stating "Class is not registered: scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map3"

Storm version 0.8.2
Chill version 0.2.3

Comment: I am getting `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Class is not registered: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer`

Comment: But i can get around this error by setting registration to false. `Kryo.setRegistrationRequired(false)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What versions are you using, you are not clear.

This is an error because scala special cases small maps, and because Storm defaults to requiring registration, and lastly because somehow, the default map serializer is not being picked up:

https://github.com/twitter/chill/blob/develop/chill-scala/src/main/scala/com/twitter/chill/KryoSerializer.scala#L108

I added an issue:
https://github.com/twitter/chill/issues/60

To work around this, set registration as optional as we do here:
https://github.com/twitter/chill/blob/develop/chill-scala/src/main/scala/com/twitter/chill/KryoBijection.scala#L38

Comment: Looks like Ryan Lecompte submitted a successful patch, so we've closed the issue: https://github.com/twitter/chill/issues/60